# Scraping a pet adoption site with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting the `div` for each pet in this website: https://indyhumane.org/adoptable-cats/ while trying to scrape details using python and Beautiful Soup

When I inspect the page and check the html source code, I see that the `div` containing each pet profile is with a `class = "mbcpp_result_animal"`, but when I use the code below, I get zero for the length of the `containers`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://indyhumane.org/adoptable-cats/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"mbcpp_result_animal"})

print(len(containers))
```

If I print `page_soup.body`, I don't see any div with `class="mbcpp_result_animal"` which is different from the html source code when I inspect the page in chrome's developer tools.

This is my first web scraping. So, I feel like I have not fully understood the process. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that comes from an additional API call the page makes to retrieve results and update the page. The call has querystring params you can see as follows.

It includes the API endpoint, an api key, criteria to restrict the search and a final random number param, presumably to avoid being served cached results. You could introduce an actual random number.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://indyhumane.org/wp-content/plugins/mbc-petpoint/mbc-petpoint-data.php?species_name=cats&sex=A&ageGroup=All&orderBy=ID&primaryBreed=All&secondaryBreed=All&specialNeeds=A&api_key=14j14u8qzj27aqw6tv53k553lxcjff0xf2uh16i61t4s61g727&num_items=-1&apimode=AdoptableSearch&location=&rnd=1')
r.json()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, I think basically it's not technically a web scraping if I need the data about pets. Right? it's just a get request as you mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM can be mutated after the initial GET request for the website. It looks like a GET request is made to:

```
https://indyhumane.org/wp-content/plugins/mbc-petpoint/mbc-petpoint-data.php
```

...with parameters that return a JSON body:

[image: inspector screenshot]

Which hydrates the list items, one-per-cat. You can still use this, but your approach may be a bit different; you can find the code that calls the endpoint in question. Going to the page source (which may be different from the code you see in the inspector), you can search for that endpoint to get the following JavaScript (formatted here):

```js
var base_url =
    "https://indyhumane.org/wp-content/plugins/mbc-petpoint/mbc-petpoint-data.php";
var num_items = -1;

function draw_petpoint_adoptable_feed_simple1(species_name) {
    draw_petpoint_adoptable_feed(1, 'AdoptableSearch', base_url,
        '14j14u8qzj27aqw6tv53k553lxcjff0xf2uh16i61t4s61g727',
        '/adopt/profile/', 'cats', 'A', 'All', 'ID', 'All', 'All', 'A', '');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    draw_petpoint_adoptable_feed_simple1('cats');
});
```

From here you can search for `draw_petpoint_adoptable_feed` which isn't in the HTML file, so you need to find it in the script files. Chrome has a handy feature for searching within sources:

[image: sources search]

And in that function, you can see the GET request being made.

Follow @QHarr's answer for how you would dynamically deal with this in your Python script.

Comment: You mentioned many good points in your answer to help me understand the process better. Thanks!